# Updating a global array

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to update a global string array with excel vba ,though I am aware  it is not the ideal way to write code.
I have simplified my requirement and here is code where I want to write values like A0,A1,A2,...  to an array . 
I am calling the Function Getone twice to simulate a case where it will be called from another Function multiple times

But unlike a global integer  -arrind , I am not able to update the Global string ,lsatest

I have declared lsatest in Module level too
I tried with  lsatest as Variant too 
I always get blank for second message box . 
what is mistake i am doing ?

```
Option Explicit
Dim arrind As Integer
Public lsatest As String


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

arrind = 0
MsgBox (Getone)
' got A1 and thats right

MsgBox (Getone)
' expecetd A1 got blank


End Sub



Public Function Getone() As String

Dim k As Integer
Dim lsatest()
For k = 0 To 2
ReDim Preserve lsatest(arrind)
lsatest(arrind) = "A" & arrind
arrind = arrind + 1
Next k
Getone = lsatest(1)

End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: "I am aware it is not the ideal way to write code" - highly suggest you do things the better way... this is just asking for problems.

Comment: Agree with BigBen. Think the immediate problem is that you declare `lsatest` twice and I think the local declaration takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

VBA resolves identifier references in the following order:

1. Local declarations (includes parameters)
2. Module declarations
3. Project-scoped declarations ("globals")
4. Globally-scoped declarations from referenced libraries (in priority order)

So, inside the `Getone` scope, the identifier `lsatest` refers to the local variable declared here:

```
Dim lsatest()
```

What's happening here is called *identifier shadowing*: the local `lsatest` is *hiding/shadowing* the module-scoped `lsatest` identifier in the next-higher scope.

If you mean for `Getone` to use the `lsatest` that's defined at module scope, then you can't have a local `lsatest` identifier.

[Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) can warn about this - and many other things:

[image: 'Shadowed Declaration' Rubberduck inspection]

<sup>"la variable" ...thank you, French Windows. That should be saying *"Variable 'VBAProject.Module1.Getone.lsatest' hides variable 'VBAProject.Module1.lsatest'."*</sup>

That said I'm not seeing any reason for any module or global variables here.

Functions should be self-contained and reliable: the fact that you are invoking the same function twice in a row and getting different results is symptomatic of a side-effecting function - avoid mixing global state and functions. The value of `arrind` is no longer `0` after the first run. If you want identical results you need identical initial state.

Comment: if I remove /comment Dim lsatest() inside the function , get "Expected Array" error when it encounters   lsatest(arrind)

Comment: Yes, because now the identifier is resolving to the module variable, which you declared `As String`; so it's getting a string, but wants an array - the next step should be pretty clear now.